# Mantaflow smoke behavior at boundaries

Tags: smoke-simulation

In Mantaflow smoke simulations, the borders of the simulation act as boundaries whether "border collisions" are on or off.   Is this the expected behavior?  It seems like it should be considered a bug.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Blender 3.0 docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.0/physics/fluid/type/domain/settings.html#border-collisions):

> **Border Collisions**
>
> Controls which sides of the domain will allow fluid “pass through” the
> domain, making it disappear without influencing the rest of the
> simulation, and which sides will deflect fluids.

So unless the documentation is incorrect, this does appear to be a bug.

[image: Smoke pooling with border collisions turned off]

Answer (score -1):

the domain walls yes.. if you add another object inside the domain, THAT object will be affected by the "collision on/off"